# Getting identical objects to show in SQL Compare

Tags: t-sql, redgate, sqlcompare

Is there a way to get SQL Compare to output all objects, specifically stored procedures, in a database and not just those that differ?

Answer (score 0):

In your compare results you should see a few different groupings.  One being "identical objects".  That one is on the bottom of my view.  I am using SQL Compare 10.

Answer (score 0):

If I want it to actually *script* all of the objects (rather than just see them in the results), I usually create an empty database and compare to that, then filter just to stored procedures and go through the synchronization wizard.